# Как сделать, чтобы при клике на плюс или минус брать значение и в отдельный блок добавлять или отнимать это значение

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть несколько одинаковый карточек, в каждой карточке есть цена, кнопка плюс и минус, а так же итоговая стоимость. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на + или - брать значение с карточки и вносить в итоговую стоимость (ниже 0 нельзя), и для каждой карточки отдельно (Не скидывал сразу сюда мои попытки на js, ибо это полная фигня выходила)

```js
const price = document.querySelectorAll('.price'),
      minus = document.querySelectorAll('.minus'),
      plus = document.querySelectorAll('.plus'),
      totalPrice = document.querySelectorAll('.total_price');


plus.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        price.forEach(elem => {
            totalPrice.forEach(res => {
               res.innerHTML = +elem;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 960px;
}

.item {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: bisque;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.price {
    margin: auto;   
    background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140)
}

.block__minus__plus {
    display: flex;
}

.minus {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 50px;
}

.plus {
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 50px;
}

.total_price {
    margin-left: 95px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
      <p class="price">200</p>
      <div class="block__minus__plus">
          <div class="minus">-</div>
          <div class="total_price">0</div>
          <div class="plus">+</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <p class="price">400</p>
      <div class="block__minus__plus">
          <div class="minus">-</div>
          <div class="total_price">0</div>
          <div class="plus">+</div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <p class="price">100</p>
      <div class="block__minus__plus">
          <div class="minus">-</div>
          <div class="total_price">0</div>
          <div class="plus">+</div>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Где Ваши попытки выполнить это задание?

Comment: Извините что сразу не скинул свои попытки, но у меня получается полная фигня и поэтому я не хотел чтобы это видели, но я все же добавил свою попытку сделать

Answer (score 2):

Почему не приложили свои попытки решения проблемы?

Сделал листалку +/-, дальше уже сами.

```js
addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains(`minus`) && !e.target.classList.contains(`plus`)) return;
  const $price = e.target.parentElement.querySelector(`.total_price`);
  $price.textContent = Math.max(0, +$price.textContent + (e.target.classList.contains(`minus`) ? -1 : 1));
})
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 960px;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: bisque;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.price {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140)
}

.block__minus__plus {
  display: flex;
}

.minus {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
}

.plus {
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
}

.total_price {
  margin-left: 95px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="price">200</p>
    <div class="block__minus__plus">
      <div class="minus">-</div>
      <div class="total_price">0</div>
      <div class="plus">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="price">400</p>
    <div class="block__minus__plus">
      <div class="minus">-</div>
      <div class="total_price">0</div>
      <div class="plus">+</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="price">100</p>
    <div class="block__minus__plus">
      <div class="minus">-</div>
      <div class="total_price">0</div>
      <div class="plus">+</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Извините что сразу не скинул мои попытки, но просто у меня получается какая-то фигня и я просто не хотел чтобы это видели, но я добавил свою попытку. Я пишу на чистом js, без Jquery. Могли бы как-то помочь именно на чистом js?

Comment: Так я в этом ответе уже сделал вам логику +|-.

Answer (score -1):

Я сам новичок в javascript, но уже есть чем поделиться. Во-первых создайте файл script.js и подключите его в конце перед тегом body.Вот так должна выглядеть строчка:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Потом, желательно изменить тег + и -(да и вообще все кнопки) на button.И добавьте параметр onclick=func() - при нажатии на кнопку будет выполняться функция func.Синтаксис такой:

```
<button onclick=func()>+<button>
```

А потом создаете в файле функцию func.И там пишите код.Весь код писать нее буду, но укажу некоторые функции: getElementsByTagName, innerHTML. Подробнее об этих функциях узнайте в инете.Надеюсь я вам хоть капельку помог

Comment: Очень благодарен за попытку помочь, но к сожалению вы не помогли. Про все что вы написали, я знаю, да и в данном примере нужно все перебирать потом через forEach, но вот чуть дальше я захожу в тупик и у меня ничего не получается:( А по поводу button, то это не обязательно, можно создавать и через div

Comment: Вы бы хоть название функций правильно указали https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: Простите, писал, как помнил и использовал очень мало. Сейчас исправлю